# How to set two different Fonts for two columns of ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, fonts

I am creating an windows application by using C#.net.In that on one form,i've a ListView with two Columns,one Containing UserID & Other Containing UserName.I would like to set two Different Fonts(like Century SchoolBook & Monotype Corsiva) for these two Columns.
How can i achieve this?Please Help me.
Thank You.

Comment: you can use data templates...

Comment: i dont know how to use data template?Please tell me how to use it?

Comment: data template is in asp.net. I think the question is related to winform

Comment: Yes.I dont know how to achieve this.So please help me.

Comment: 1. Add a datagridview to your winform from toolbox 2. select a control type for each column from datagrid property window 3. you can set the font from same properties window.

Comment: Ok.i will try it.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Make these two columns as label columns and then you can easily set a different font for two different labels.

Following example explains how a button is added to a column. Same logic can be used to add labels.

[Adding button into a Listview in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456063/adding-button-into-a-listview-in-winforms)

Comment: i just realized that Grid control will be useful in your case. eaiser than the proposed solution above.