# Add button to C# win for application dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I am developing a program in Windows Form Application, and fetching values from MS Access in listview form. But i need to auto add a delete button so i would delete any specific entry on click.

```
private void loading_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source = Database21.accdb";
        con.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from newdb2", con);
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(myRow[0].ToString());
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRow[1].ToString());
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRow[2].ToString());
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRow[3].ToString());
            listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRow[4].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
    }
}
```

So in above code data inserting in proper way but i also want buton to b auto add in last column.

Please help in this matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't be Statham. I recommend you to use context menu instead. Easier. Or single button outside to remove selected items. Way easier. Otherwise it's a [duplicate of going hard (Statham?) way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/456063/1997232).

Comment: ListView by default does not allow button columns. You can of course extend the control and do it. However, you can use a DataGridView and make use of button column to reduce the amount of code you need.