# How to add a button to a column or subitem in a ListView in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, frontend

I am having a terrible time trying to figure out how to list a button with a value on a listview to go with each value.

[image: What I currently have]

I need to replace all of the add/edit string values with Buttons. The original assignment was for a listbox but I figured that the only way too accomplish this is through subitems from listview items. Thanks.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Columns.Add("Samples", 90);
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Columns.Add("AddEdit", 60);
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Columns.Add("Delete", 45);

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("1");
        item.SubItems.Add("add/edit");
        item.SubItems.Add("x");
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Items.Add(item);

        ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("2");
        item2.SubItems.Add("add/edit");
        item2.SubItems.Add("x");
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Items.Add(item2);

        ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("3");
        item3.SubItems.Add("add/edit");
        item3.SubItems.Add("x");
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Items.Add(item3);

        ListViewItem item4 = new ListViewItem("4");
        item4.SubItems.Add("add/edit");
        item4.SubItems.Add("x");
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Items.Add(item4);

        ListViewItem item5 = new ListViewItem("5");
        item5.SubItems.Add("add/edit");
        item5.SubItems.Add("x");
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Items.Add(item5);

        ListViewItem item6 = new ListViewItem("6");
        item6.SubItems.Add("add/edit");
        item6.SubItems.Add("x");
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Items.Add(item6);

        ListViewItem item7 = new ListViewItem("7");
        item7.SubItems.Add("add/edit");
        item7.SubItems.Add("x");
        this.DefinedClassesLb.Items.Add(item7);

        this.DefinedClassesLb.View = View.Details;
        this.DefinedClassesLb.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not datagridview? then simply declare the desired column as a button column

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll likely have to dig into OwnerDraw to accomplish this.  See the `ListViewExtender` class in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4545340/90476).

Comment: `I am having a terrible time...` - I suggest you take a look at WPF as an alternative to winforms, so you can just do whatever you need without wasting a lof of time fighting the incapabilities of an ancient framework.

Comment: I agree with Nissim, Is it a possibility for you to switch to DataGridView instead of ListView ? DataGridView has a lot of features which are absent in ListView.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` control is a terrible host for other controls. It simply doesn't play well with them. Specifically, it doesn't handle focus properly, and most particularly does not provide a scrollable panel for subcontrols. This last problem is the true killer.

Your options are:

1. As suggested, use `DataGridView`.
2. Use `ObjectListView`. This is an open source wrapper around a standard .NET ListView, which gives it super powers! Like [displaying buttons](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-put-a-description-under-something-that-looks-like-a-title)!

[image]

Even here, the button is not hosted -- the control itself does a lot of work to make make something look and act like a button.