# Adding button in listview as subitem VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Good day. I have this problem in listview. I want to add control button in listview in every corresponding data. what I mean is every row that has data the control button named "Update" will also display at last column in listview. the code below doesn't work and I dont have any idea how to work this out.

```
    Dim li As ListViewItem
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter

    connect()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Data"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn)
    da.Fill(dt)
    lv.Items.Clear()
    For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        li = lv.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(0).ToString)
        li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(1).ToString)
        li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(2).ToString)
        li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(3).ToString)
        li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(4).ToString)
        li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(5).ToString)
        li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(6).ToString)
        li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows(i).ItemArray(7).ToString)

    Next

    Dim b = New Button
    b.Name = "update"
    b.Text = "UPDATE"
    lv.Controls.Add(b)
```

Comment: This might help. [Adding buttons into a Listview in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456063/adding-button-into-a-listview-in-winforms)

Comment: The ListView is a bad choice for DB apps. not only do you have to create each row and each column but also everything is string.  Using a DataGridView is much easier **and** it already has a button column type

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom class something like this:

```
Public Class CustomItem
    Inherits ListViewItem

    Public customButton As Button

    Public Sub New(ByVal buttonText As String, ByRef listView As ListView)
        Me.Text = buttonText
        listView.Items.Add(Me)
        customButton = New Button
        customButton.Left = Me.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire).Left
        customButton.Left = Me.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire).Left
        customButton.Width = Me.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Entire).Width
        customButton.Text = buttonText
        listView.Controls.Add(customButton)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then insert a new `CustomItem` into the `ListView` like this:

```
Dim item As New CustomItem("Update", ListView1)
```

That's a start.  There's a lot of functionality that it doesn't implement, but you can add to that.

Comment: for now i can display the button in listview but i want this button to display as subitem.