# Add controls into flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, dynamic-controls, flowlayoutpanel

In a Windows form, I can add controls into flowlayoutpanel dynamically by doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    butto.Name="btn_"+i.ToSting();
    butto.Text=i.ToSting();
    this.flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

It works very well, but when I set the variable 'i' to 1500, it seems like the flowlayoutpanel cannot display all its controls. Where is the error, and how can I solve?

What I want to do is create a user control which contains a flowlayoutpanel, and when I open a PDF document, I want to add an item which display thumbnails of each page into the flowlayoutpanel.

Comment: are you add only button or more controls ? One WinForm control limit; 6000. becuse form handle table is 64k

Comment: *"it seems like the flowlayoutpanel cannot display all its controls"* - how did you came to such conclusion? Are they not visible? Got a screenshot to show? Adding so many controls comes at cost, have you thought about using specialized controls to represent many items, e.g. [`ListView`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/456063/1997232)?

Comment: How many 20 pound pigs fit into a 100 pound poke?  Not 1500.  Set the panel's AutoScroll property to True to get ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `flowlayoutpanel.AutoScroll = true` in code or by design Property you can set AutoScroll by default true.